# Flutter lack performance when use clip path

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-clippath

I have this situation using a flutter component, the performance with widgets completely created with clip path have a bad performance. There is a way to prevent a bad performance with many clip paths?

[image]

Comment: Did you try creating and using a `const` constructor for the `CustomClipper<Path>` class?

Comment: The image example is from the test I make  with the [flutter chat bubble](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_chat_bubble), but a CustomClipper got the same result, I test with 500 elements and the drop is high.